# how to create an empty rewrite rule, that will not modify the url

Tags: mod-rewrite

I have static files in several directories on my website.
I was trying to create a rule that will instruct the rewrite engine to disregard all of those static files.

something like this:

```
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.*(jpg|css|js|gif|png|swf)$ [NC]
```

this seems to work only in some of the cases, but not all of them.

As a solution I decided to match the entire request URI of any requested file with one of the following extensions, and create an 'empty' rewrite rule for them, that will redirect the user to the precise request URL, basically.

To achieve that I did the following:

```
RewriteCond $1 \*.(js|ico|gif|jpg|png|css|swf|mp3|wav|txt)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*) \$1  [R=301,L]
```

This won't work for some reason, no useful information at the access.log and error.log either.
Thanks in advance for any assistance!

Full code:

```
#Catch static content and don't modify it
RewriteCond $1 \*.(js|ico|gif|jpg|png|css|swf|mp3|wav|txt)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*) \$1  [R=301,L]

#prevent looping
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !clientId=

#redirect sub domain to the client page cutl.mysite.com = mysite.com/in/index/php?clientId=curl
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /in/index.php?uclinetId=$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 1):

Rather than maintaining a long list of file extensions for exclusion you can simply use:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
```

Which means apply next RewriteRule if request is NOT for a real file or a symbolic link.

Comment: This way Apache serves only part of the files, mostly images, basically my problem to begin with.

Comment: Actually it is other way. This way Apache doesn't rewrite URLs of static files. Note use of`!-` in RewriteCont for negation.

Answer (score 1):

Probably your backslash should be between the asterix and the dot?

```
RewriteCond $1 *\.(js|ico|gif|jpg|png|css|swf|mp3|wav|txt)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*) \$1  [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Make perfect sense, but resulted in an internal server error (500)

Comment: And if you replace the first * by (.*)? (in your RewriteCond-line)

Comment: Doesn't give the desired result either.
Thanks for trying to help though :)